# I have ADFS implemented on SP 2013 and would like to use the 2013 farm to crawl another 2010 farm, need some advice

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a 2013 farm(ADFS) and i trying to crawl my 2010 farm(Claims-NTLM),the approach i was planning for is

1. Use Publishing/Consuming Concept - This will not work since 2013
   cannot consume any service application from 2010 whereas viceversa
   it will work
2. Create Federated Result Source - This concept crawls the indexes of
   the 2010 farm and returns results in 2013 - I am not sure how to do
   that any help is appreciate.

Please let me know if there is any any other feasible way to accomplish this.Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you cannot consume from 2010 to 2013 farm.But you can consume the services from 2013 to 2010.

In order to search 2010 content in 2013.

- Build a trust between 2010 & 2013 Farm
- Publish Search Services in 2013 Farm
- Consume it on 2010 Farm.
- Set the permission
- Create content source.
- run full crawl.

http://www.maadarani.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=9